# Python reading rows from csv, operating and organizing rows of numbers

Tags: python, csv, statistics, time-series

I am a non-programmer geographer, heard some programming concepts but very newby :-)

1. I am to read six rows of environmental data. 1000 lines at the most, each time.
2. Each row housing two digit numbers (0 to 99) a summer issue, only positive numbers.
3. Once I read them I am to display the numbers 0 to 99 vertically with the number of occurrences for the reading  for each of the six rows:

0 = 230.....0 = 3........0 = 230......0 = 123......0 = 223......0 = 334

1 = 67......1 = 657......1 = 627......1 = 767......1 = 467......1 = 337

2 = 762.....2 = 328......2 = 987......2 = 326......2 = 32.......2 = 123

.
.

99 = 3.....99 = 34.......99 = 1.......99 = 89......99 = 78......99 = 123

If I can get this far I will feel great. Once I learn how to do this and I can look at the data I can decide what makes sense to run next; excel, graphs, statistics, statistics in R, get the numbers into a matrix to manipulate from there, etc.  First time so I am figuring this out as I go.

Any help will be much appreciated,

Adolfo
I am working in the research for the restoration of Quebrada Verde watershed in Valparaiso, Chile.

Comment: Hi Adolfo, in term of 'rows', are you talking about columns indeed? Could you give an example on the csv file format? Ta

Comment: Hi Adolfo, I find what you are trying to do interesting and I respect it as well. Sharing sample of your input file would be a good way to move forward.

Comment: Yes DAG you are right, my apologies; the data comes in 5 to eight COLUMNS of + - 20,000  row files. I am thinking to choose .txt files instead of .csv for the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 0):

```
from array import array
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    count = array('H', [0]*100)
    file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    if file:
        for line in file:
            count[int(line)]+=1
        file.close()
        for a in range (100):
            print(a, count[a], sep='\t')
    else:
        print('unable to open the file')
else:
    print('usage: python', sys.argv[0], ' file')
```

Comment: OK :-) now I have something specific to my task to decipher on my way to learn Python. Thank you very much.....

Comment: Lots of concepts implied in eaah line :-)  I just read that "len" is a built-in function to determine the number of items in an object. Questions: 1. does the line: if len(sys.argv) > 1:  means that you are asking if the first line is not empty read it to this array? and the "object" for len is the file you are reading from? 2. In the array cero is the minimum and 100 the maximum; what's H?

Comment: @Adolfo `len(sys.argv)>1` means that more than one argument is passed to the program. `array('H', [0]*100)` means an array of 100 2-byte unsigned integer. `'H'` means 2-byte unsigned integer, or unsigned short.